# How do I stop the output from being printed in jshell

Tags: output, declaration, jshell

How do I stop the output being printed?

I don't want it to be like this

```
i=15
$1==15
```

I just want it to be processed without the output being printed

I tried looking everywhere and trying new lines of code and searching online and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Set the right mode in your shell with:

```
/set feedback concise
```

There are four different ***mode*** for feedback you can use in jshell:

```
/set feedback
|
|  Available feedback modes:
|     concise
|     normal
|     silent
|     verbose
```

Maybe you look at the various settings in shell with:

```
/help set
```